# Getting Errors In My Activity Switching App

Tags: android, button, android-activity, syntax-error

Hello I am trying to fix my app that features a progress bar as well as a button that switches to a new activity. Could someone please help me isolate my errors and give me a solution to the problem? I am very new at android programming!

Here is my main activity. I have bolded where I am receiving errors. Here I get an error saying "Activity 1 Must be defined in its own file"

```
package com.example.progressdialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


   public class mainactivity2 {

    }
private ProgressDialog progress;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
   }


   public void open(View view){
      progress.setMessage("Progressing Along!");
      progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
      progress.setIndeterminate(false);
      progress.show();

   final int totalProgressTime = 100;

   final Thread t = new Thread(){

   @Override
   public void run(){

      int jumpTime = 0;
      while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime){
         try {
            sleep(500);
            jumpTime += 1;
            progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {


           e.printStackTrace();
         }

      }

   }
   };
   t.start();

   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }
}

public class **Activity1** extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Here is my second activity file. I once again bolded where I am having errors. This one says I am missing a bracket to complete method body, but I cannot seem to figure out where to put it.

```
package com.example.progressdialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity2 extends Activity **{**

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }

        })**;**
```

Thank you! I just need to figure out how to correct these errors because I have gotten them a few times before, if you could explain why the errors are occurring that would help me also.

Comment: My boldings came out as ** sorry about that!

Comment: please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @Emmanuel Have you read the question?

Comment: Posting the stacktrace is something that should be done regardless of the simplicity of the error. Even if it is just to get in the habit, specially for new developers.

Comment: I am not to sure what the stacktrace is, but I assume it is this:

Syntax error, insert } to complete class body   Line- 25
public activity type must be defined            Line- 69

Comment: @Emmanuel You're right, but in this case there is no stacktrace as Eclipse won't even let him run that code.

Comment: @user3186489 Error messages often tell us exactly what the problem is. In this case, you even get a hint of a potential solution!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, each `Activity` should be defined in its own `.java` file and declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I dont understand, my activity is declared in my android manifest already

Comment: I have corrected it in my AndroidManifest.xml but now I have a new error: "MainActivit is already defined"

Comment: You should give your `Activities` different names.

Comment: I think I have some sort of formatting issue. My first block of code is from MainActivity.java. My second is from Activity2.java.

I believe I am using MainActivity twice in my first block of code. Once for the progress bar, and again for the button to change pages. How can I correct this? Can I combine those into one oncreate?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the closing brackets at the end of your activity. You seem to be missing not one but two closing brackets btw. Every time you open a bracket `{` you also have to close it `}`. 
Brackets are used to structure code, for example to define a method body or a class.

Tip 1: Use Eclipse's auto formatting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>), it will align opening & closing brackets with each other.

Tip 2: Highlight one bracket and Eclipse will highlight it's corresponding opening / closing bracket so you can see which belongs to which.

You'll get a feeling for how code is structured by brackets soon ;)

Also, as Emmanuel answered, every Activity should be declared in it's own file.

Comment: Thank you I did't realize I was missing two brackets!