# Error: The Type MainActivity Is Already Defined

Tags: android, button, syntax-error

I am working on getting the final kinks out of an example app I am doing. I have solved many of my problems by getting help from people on stackoverflow, but I still cannot get this last thing fixed! Could someone edit this code so I do not get the error "The type MainActivity is already defined" the second time I use it? I can see why this is bad formatting but I do not know how to fix it! Here is the code:

```
package com.example.progressdialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


   public class mainactivity2 {

    }
private ProgressDialog progress;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
   }


   public void open(View view){
      progress.setMessage("Progressing!");
      progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
      progress.setIndeterminate(false);
      progress.show();

   final int totalProgressTime = 100;

   final Thread t = new Thread(){

   @Override
   public void run(){

      int jumpTime = 0;
      while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime){
         try {
            sleep(500);
            jumpTime += 1;
            progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {


           e.printStackTrace();
         }

      }

   }
   };
   t.start();

   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357402/getting-errors-in-my-activity-switching-app) one you asked an hour ago.

Comment: No it is not. I changed the question as well as my code.

Comment: Only define one `Activity` at a time.  If you want to have more than one, define them in separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `MainActivity` twice. And also for some reason you have an inner mainactivity2 class inside your first MainActivity.

Comment: How do I correct to define MainActivity only once?

 I have removed the redundant code mainactivity2, thank you!

Comment: Just remove the second class definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

??? You are trying to define MainActivity twice. Did you see?

Comment: Yes I do see! But I cannot figure out how to change that. I am very new to programming, how can I make both of the commands go under the first MainActivity extends?

Comment: You could not define 2 classes in the same package. :( Please tell me what would you like to do?

Comment: I am trying to have my first activity have one button that starts the progress bar, and another button that brings me to my second activity. Right now my button for progress bar is working, but I dont know how to set up the wiring for the second button.

Comment: Try is yourself: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html